# Conditional Formatting in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create conditional formatting for multiple columns in a spreadsheet so I chomped this code and modified as follows:

```
Function ConditionalFormatOneNo()
Dim rgO As Range
Dim rgP As Range
Dim rgQ As Range
Dim rgR As Range
Dim rqS As Range
Dim cond As FormatCondition

Set rgO = Range("O:O")
Set rgP = Range("P:P")
Set rgQ = Range("Q:Q")
Set rgR = Range("R:R")
Set rgS = Range("S:S")

'apply conditional formatting to any cell in columns  with value greater than 30
Set cond = rgO.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "NO")
Set cond = rgP.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "NO")
Set cond = rgQ.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "NO")
Set cond = rgR.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "NO")
Set cond = rgS.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "NO")

'define conditional formatting to use
With cond
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

End Function
```

Column O and Column S are both updating correctly however P, Q, R are not taking the conditional formatting.

I have a separate function created for each option YES NO And EMPTY

Thoughts, comments solution appreciated

Answer (score 1):

- Your code created 5 CF rules for each column. However the top 4 don't have any formatting.
- btw, If you don't require return values or objects from the procedure, please use `Sub` instead of `Function`.

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConditionalFormatOneNo()
    Dim rgOS As Range
    Dim cond As FormatCondition
    
    Set rgOS = Range("O:S")
    
    'apply conditional formatting to any cell in columns  with value greater than 30
    Set cond = rgOS.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "NO")
    
    'define conditional formatting to use
    With cond
        .Interior.Color = vbRed
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

---

Update:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConditionalFormatOneAll()
    ConditionalFormatOne Null, vbRed
    ConditionalFormatOne "NO", vbRed
    ConditionalFormatOne "YES", vbGreen
End Sub

Sub ConditionalFormatOne(ByVal sKey As Variant, ByVal iColor As Long)
    Dim rgOS As Range
    Dim cond As FormatCondition
    Set rgOS = Range("O:S, V:AE, AG:AJ")
    Set cond = rgOS.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, sKey)
    'define conditional formatting to use
    With cond
        .Interior.Color = iColor
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah that is much cleaner. Thanks. added some minor additional code to the first sub.

Comment: Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    WS.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. This is what I used for the overall solution that works

```
Sub ConditionalFormatOneNo()
Dim rgOS As Range

Dim cond As FormatCondition

Set rgOS = Range("O:S, V:AE, AG:AJ")

Set cond = rgOS.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "NO")
'define conditional formatting to use
With cond
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
End Sub

Sub ConditionalFormatOneYes()
Dim rgOS As Range
Dim cond As FormatCondition
'specify range to apply conditional formatting
Set rgOS = Range("O:S, V:AE, AG:AJ")
Set cond = rgOS.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "YES")

'define conditional formatting to use
With cond
.Interior.Color = vbGreen
.Font.Color = vbBlack
.Font.Bold = True
End With

End Sub

Sub ConditionalFormatOneEmpty()
Dim rgOS As Range
Dim cond As FormatCondition
'specify range to apply conditional formatting
Set rgOS = Range("O:S, V:AE, AG:AJ")

Set cond = rgOS.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, Null)

'define conditional formatting to use
With cond
.Interior.Color = vbRed
.Font.Color = vbBlack
.Font.Bold = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The majority of the three subs are the same. You may consider refactoring them into a single sub. Please see my updated answer.